# iOS dependences not resolving in Kotlin MultiPlatform Project

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, build.gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to develop a small library to post issues to my company's Jira server, and I thought that a Kotlin MPP w/ [KTOR](https://ktor.io/) would be just the ticket.

At first, following a few tutorials, I made a shared project, and the imports for iOS were working fine but Android's Ktor implementation would not resolve. Then I realized that I needed to recreate the project and create a library instead of a shared application, as I have existing codebases for each mobile client already, and I need to publish the MPP library to be used by them.

Upon recreating the project as a library, and simply starting to add the dependencies for [KTOR 1.3.2](https://bintray.com/kotlin/ktor/ktor/1.3.2), the iOS dependencies are failing to resolve. This is not just KTOR, it is any iOS dependency, so there's obviously something incorrect in my project setup, but I am unable to spot it.

Here is the gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform' version '1.3.72'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
}

group 'com.example.issuereporter'
version '0.0.1'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

kotlin {

    targets {
        final def iOSTarget = System.getenv('SDK_NAME')?.startsWith("iphoneos") ? presets.iosArm64 : presets.iosX64

        fromPreset(iOSTarget, 'ios') {
            binaries {
                framework('IssueReporter')
            }
        }


        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
    }

    def ktor_version = "1.3.2"

    sourceSets["commonMain"].dependencies {
        implementation kotlin('stdlib-common')

        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version"
    }

    sourceSets["commonTest"].dependencies {
        implementation kotlin('test-common')
        implementation kotlin('test-annotations-common')
    }

    sourceSets["androidMain"].dependencies {
        implementation kotlin('stdlib')

        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-auth-jvm:$ktor_version"

    }

    sourceSets["androidTest"].dependencies {
        implementation kotlin('test')
        implementation kotlin('test-junit')
    }

    sourceSets["iosMain"].dependencies {
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-native:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-native:$ktor_version"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:$ktor_version"
    }


}

configurations {
    compileClasspath
}


task packForXcode(type: Sync) {
    final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    final String mode = project.findProperty("XCODE_CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: 'DEBUG'
    final def framework = kotlin.targets.ios.binaries.getFramework("IssueReporter", mode)

    inputs.property "mode", mode
    dependsOn framework.linkTask

    from { framework.outputFile.parentFile }
    into frameworkDir

    doLast {
        new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
            text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
            setExecutable(true)
        }
    }
}

tasks.build.dependsOn packForXcode
```

The console output is

```
Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:1.3.2.
Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-core-native:1.3.2.
Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-json-native:1.3.2.
Could not resolve io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-native:1.3.2.
```

Anything obvious that I am missing here?

**UPDATE**

I scrapped and recreated the project w/ an updated version of IntelliJ (IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.5 (Community Edition)) & the Kotlin 1.4.0 Plugin installed. This gave me a slightly different creation wizard, and the option to use Kotlin as the Gradle syntax.

Updated `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.4.0"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.0"
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
}
group = "com.example.issuereporter"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
    maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor")
    maven(url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/")
    maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    maven(url = "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
}
kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "library"
            }
        }
    }

    val ktor_version = "1.3.2"
    val serialization_version = "0.20.0"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-apache:$ktor_version")

                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0")

                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth-jvm:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktor_version")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktor_version")
                implementation ("io.ktor:ktor-client-core-native:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json-native:$ktor_version")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth-native:$ktor_version")
            }
        }
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

The gradle dependencies for iOS successfully sync when I set the `ktor_version` to `1.3.2` but not for `1.4.0` (assuming the mirrors haven't updated for the native files??)... but the imports don't compile when I attempt to utilize the class at all... see attached image:

[image]

Comment: Just keep the ones in `commonMain` and remove everything else with `...-core-xyz` on other platforms specific; For example remove `io.ktor:ktor-client-core-native`

Comment: For kotlin 1.4.0 just follow what Dr.jacky said. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/migrating-multiplatform-project-to-14.html

Comment: how does that work? won't the native implementations fail?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you don't have `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` in `settings.gradle`.

[`settings.gradle`](https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit/blob/master/settings.gradle.kts#L3)

Check our starter project [KaMPKit](https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit) for a running example on 1.3.72. We'll probably bump that to 1.4.0 this week, but for now it should be a good reference.

Comment: aha! I forgot to mention this, but I do!

`
rootProject.name = 'IssueReporter'


enableFeaturePreview('GRADLE_METADATA')
`

Comment: (but i will check the starter kit, thx! - and thx for all your work + evangelism on Kotlin MPP so far!)

Comment: Feels like ktor-client-core-native 1.4.0 is not released yet. At least it is missing in puplic repositories https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ktor/ktor-client-core-native. Btw I'm trying to migrate KaMPKit on 1.4 now and expecting exact same issue.

Comment: Yeah, agree. But i think I have a deeper issue - my gradle syncs for 1.3.2 but the IDE doesn't resolve any of the imports.

Comment: KaMPKit for 1.4.0 is dependent on a number of libraries. I'm currently wrestling with sqldelight. 1.4.0 is a major update, and there are a number of config issues, unrelated to "native", so the library ecosystem will take more time than usual to get sorted. Making progress, though. Wish me luck...

Comment: does TouchLab have an example of an actual MPP library that is open source / available for reference? (ie. one that just includes common/android/ios code and not an accompanying app module) ???

Comment: @KevinGalligan Once you update to Gradle 6.0, you can remove `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` from the project’s `settings.gradle` file. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/migrating-multiplatform-project-to-14.html#simplify-your-build-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Here are my dependencies (I have separate iOS targets, but it should still help you):

```
        iosEmulatorMain.dependencies {
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutinesVersion"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serializationVersion"
            implementation "com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-iosx64:$klockVersion"
            implementation "com.github.aakira:napier-iosX64:$napierVersion"
        }
        iosDeviceMain.dependencies {
            implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:$coroutinesVersion"
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serializationVersion"
            implementation "com.soywiz.korlibs.klock:klock-iosarm64:$klockVersion"
            implementation "com.github.aakira:napier-iosArm64:$napierVersion"
        }
```

Versions:

```
ktorVersion=1.3.2
```

Repositories:

```
    maven(url = "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx")
    maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor")
    maven(url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/")
    maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    maven(url = "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
```

To configure client serializer try to write it like this:

```
install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true 
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks... this still isn't working, and I don't see any difference in your dependency declaration, only your repositories...

Comment: I also find it odd that I would need other repositories - the guide at https://ktor.io/quickstart/quickstart/gradle.html just mentions `jcenter()` and the guide at https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/multiplatform.html doesn't mention anything, so I assume that's unchanged...

Comment: Thx. Are you adding the serialization plugin?

Comment: Yes, like this plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}

Comment: I can get the imports to work momentarily, but it just gives up and fails to resolve after a few gradle syncs... this feels hopeless. I'm pretty confident that it's something to do with my local project structure though...